# How to hide the offcanvas navbar when selecting the links inside of it using react scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap, react-scroll

Any idea on how to hide/back to its original state when selecting the links inside offcanvas using react scroll?

Below is my code and also here is the sandbox code [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/offcanvas-react-scroll-mghhyz).

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HeaderContent from "./components/Header";
import Content from "./components/Content";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <header>
        <HeaderContent />
      </header>

      <main className="flex-shrink-0">
        <React.Suspense fallback={<h6>Loading...</h6>}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Content />} />
          </Routes>
        </React.Suspense>
      </main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Offcanvas, Navbar, Nav, Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";

const Header = () => {
  const offsetValue = -56;

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand={false} fixed="top">
        <Container fluid>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#">Navbar Offcanvas</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar" />
          <Navbar.Offcanvas
            id="offcanvasNavbar"
            aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel"
            placement="end"
          >
            <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
              <Offcanvas.Title id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
                Offcanvas
              </Offcanvas.Title>
            </Offcanvas.Header>
            <Offcanvas.Body>
              <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3 offcanvas--menu">
                <Link
                  activeClass="active"
                  to="home"
                  spy={true}
                  smooth={true}
                  offset={offsetValue}
                  duration={500}
                  className="p-3 border-bottom border-dark text-decoration-none"
                >
                  Home
                </Link>
                <Link
                  activeClass="active"
                  to="about"
                  spy={true}
                  smooth={true}
                  offset={offsetValue}
                  duration={500}
                  className="p-3 border-bottom border-dark text-decoration-none"
                >
                  About
                </Link>
                <Link
                  activeClass="active"
                  to="contact"
                  spy={true}
                  smooth={true}
                  offset={offsetValue}
                  duration={500}
                  className="p-3 border-bottom border-dark text-decoration-none"
                >
                  Contact
                </Link>
              </Nav>
            </Offcanvas.Body>
          </Navbar.Offcanvas>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**Content.js**

```
const Content = () => (
  <>
    <div className="pt-4">
      <div id="home">
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="about">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="contact">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
);

export default Content;
```

Im using the ff:
react 17.0.2
[react-router-dom 6.2.2](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6)
[react-scroll 1.8.7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll)
react-bootstrap offcanvas 2.1.2 https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/offcanvas/

I'm not sure if I missed something like `useState/useEffect` or an `attribute` to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a fan of bootstrap and I'm sure there's a more vanilla Javascript/boostrap method for achieving this, but here's a simple implementation using some local state.

1. Add a `show` state that can be toggled true/false.
2. Add an `onClick` handler to the `Navbar.Toggle` component to handle opening the `OffCanvas` component.
3. Add the `show` and `onHide` props to the `Navbar.Offcanvas` to handle showing/hiding the `OffCanvas` component.
4. Add an `onClick` handler to each `Link` component to toggle the `show` state.

Code

```
const Header = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const offsetValue = -56;

  const toggleOffCanvas = () => {
    setShow((show) => !show);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar ... >
        <Container fluid>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#">Navbar Offcanvas</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle
            aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar"
            onClick={toggleOffCanvas}
          />
          <Navbar.Offcanvas
            ...
            show={show}
            onHide={toggleOffCanvas}
          >
            <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
              ...
            </Offcanvas.Header>
            <Offcanvas.Body>
              <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3 offcanvas--menu">
                <Link
                  ...
                  onClick={toggleOffCanvas}
                >
                  Home
                </Link>
                <Link
                  ...
                  onClick={toggleOffCanvas}
                >
                  About
                </Link>
                <Link
                  ...
                  onClick={toggleOffCanvas}
                >
                  Contact
                </Link>
              </Nav>
            </Offcanvas.Body>
          </Navbar.Offcanvas>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit offcanvas-react-scroll (forked)]

### Update

Simpler implementation using a React ref.

1. Create a ref for the `Navbar.OffCanvas` component.
2. Create an `onClick` handler to access the attached ref, the `backdrop` element, and simulate a click event.
3. Add an `onClick` handler to each `Link` component to toggle the `Navbar.OffCanvas` component hidden.

Code

```
const Header = () => {
  const offCanvasRef = useRef();
  const offsetValue = -56;

  const closeOffCanvas = () => offCanvasRef.current.backdrop.click();

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand={false} fixed="top">
        <Container fluid>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#">Navbar Offcanvas</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar" />
          <Navbar.Offcanvas
            ref={offCanvasRef}
            ...
          >
            <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
              ...
            </Offcanvas.Header>
            <Offcanvas.Body>
              <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3 offcanvas--menu">
                <Link
                  ...
                  onClick={closeOffCanvas}
                >
                  Home
                </Link>
                <Link
                  ...
                  className="p-3 border-bottom border-dark text-decoration-none"
                  onClick={closeOffCanvas}
                >
                  About
                </Link>
                <Link
                  ...
                  onClick={closeOffCanvas}
                >
                  Contact
                </Link>
              </Nav>
            </Offcanvas.Body>
          </Navbar.Offcanvas>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-hide-the-offcanvas-navbar-when-selecting-the-links-inside-of-it-using-rea (with Ref)]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative for the acccepted answer, if you like to use HTML property to close the offcanvas nav.
You just need to add `data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"` to the `offcanvas`. This will create a behaviour, which when we click the offcanvas wrapper it will close itself.

Example for `a` tag:

```
<div class="offcanvas" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">
  ...
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    <a href="/about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This workaround works well with `next/script` module.
For example:

```
<div class="offcanvas" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">
  ...
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    <Link href="/about" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">About</Link>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Source**: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/#offcanvas-components
**Bootstrap version**: 5.2

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" class="nav-item mt-3 me-3">
              <Link to="/home" class="custom-item nav-link">
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mt-3 me-3">
              <a class="custom-item nav-link" href="#">
                About
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mt-3 me-3 dropdown">
              <a
                class="nav-link custom-item dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Countries
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">
                  <Link to="/china" class="fw-bold dropdown-item">
                    China
                  </Link>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider"></hr>
                </li>
                <li data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">
                  <Link to="/japan" class="fw-bold dropdown-item">
                    Japan
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider"></hr>
                </li>
                <li data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">
                  <Link to="/korea" class="fw-bold dropdown-item">
                    Korea
                  </Link>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider"></hr>
                </li>
                <li data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">
                  <Link to="/taiwan" class="fw-bold dropdown-item">
                    Taiwan
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mt-3 me-3">
              <a class="custom-item fw-bold nav-link" href="#">
                Contacts
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: For me it worked this way: I simply add the data-bs-dismiss='offcanvas' to the li tag without adding anything else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).